# Docker image doesn't change after editing the files inside

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I clone the docker image from:
https://github.com/twtrubiks/docker-django-nginx-uwsgi-postgres-tutorial

I execute "docker-compose up" and the containers are created as expected.
However, if I edit the files inside /api folder and execute "docker-compose up" again, the contains remains the same content as before.

I've already try the following command but no luck

```
docker-compose rm --all 
docker-compose pull 
docker-compose build --no-cache 
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

Comment: Up is for creating container from image. Did you try stop/start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `docker-compose` run, if the `volume` already exists which you define in `docker-compose.yml`, `docker` re-use it, not re-creating.

It means that `api_data` `volume` may be created at the first time you run. after that docker has re-used the same `volume` where `/api` data is not changed.

Try again after removing `api_data` volume so that `docker` can re-create the volume where `/api` is changed.

First of all, check the `volume` name with the command.

```
$ docker volume ls
```

The command list all `volumes` created in your `docker` host. the volume's name would be a string containing `api_data`, for example, `docker-django-nginx-uwsgi-postgres-tutorial-api-data` or something.

Then delete that with the command.

```
$ docker volume rm $(volume-name)  

# $(volume-name) should be the volume name from docker volume ls
```

As the other way, You could change `/api` in the `volume` directly.

Check the `volume` mount path with the command.

```
$ docker volume inspect $(volume-name)
```

From the output, you can see `Mountpoint`, That is where the `volume` is mounted.

```
$ su                  # You need root permission to access mount-directory
$ cd $(Mountpoint)
$ ls  

# Change file you want
```

Comment: It says "Error: No such volume: api_data"

Comment: @Gary Ng Even though you delete `containers` and `images`, the volume will be alive. check the volume name by `docker volume ls` then delete that by `docker volume rm $(volume_name)`.

Comment: It's probably named something like "dockerdjangonginxuwsgipostgrestutorial_api_data".   Try running `docker volume ls` to find exact name for your environment, then rm that volume.

Comment: Oops - sorry, just saw that @SangminKim said the same thing above :)